# What is the meaning of "Fifty Shades of Grey"?

Tags: title, fifty-shades-of-grey

In the *Fifty Shades of Grey* movie, the protagonist was named Christian Grey.

So was the title of the movie related to the protagonist? Is there some deeper meaning to the title?

Comment: The phrase "50 shades" appears in Three Men in a Boat - a comic Victorian novel by Jerome K Jerome. In Chapter 6 he writes "There are fifty shades and tints and hues in every ten yards of that old wall" - a bit less exciting than 50 shades of grey, but certainly similar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a topic of discussion in my book club last year.  I was referred to the following [article](http://www.bustle.com/articles/61979-what-does-fifty-shades-of-greys-title-mean-the-symbolism-goes-deeper-than-youd-think):

> So what is the title of Fifty Shades of Grey referring to? There are a
>   few options. On the surface, Fifty Shades of Grey means roughly what
>   you think it means: Christian Grey has a lot of facets of his
>   personality. He can go from gentleman one minute to S&M manic the
>   next. The book is showcasing all those shades of Grey's character.
>
> But the title is also a play on words. The phrase "shades of gray"
>   usually refers to a situation that is not clear, particularly with
>   regard to whether or not something is categorically evil. When doubt
>   comes into play, things are neither black, nor white, but are in a
>   gray area. Of course, Christian's last name allowed the author to
>   title the book the very clever Fifty Shades of Grey with it's unique
>   spelling of his last name.
>
> As for the number 50, there are a lot of speculations as to why the
>   author chose that number. Interestingly, data has found that the human
>   eye can only see 32 shades of gray. So perhaps by choosing a number
>   higher than that, the author is telling readers that you can't see all
>   of the facets of Grey's character, and therefore you cannot judge him
>   if you don't have the full picture. It reinforces that theme of
>   "shades of gray" confusion.

Comment: "with it's unique spelling of his last name." Grey is the standard spelling in British English. The author is British. (See also: Earl Grey.)

Comment: So, is Grey the standard British English spelling for the color as well?

Comment: Of course, that is what I meant.

Comment: Sorry...misunderstood, you referenced "Earl Grey" which I presumed was just a name.   I believe that the author intended for it to be a play on words with the color and the name...hence the word "shades" in the title.

Comment: Sure, but there is no unique spelling of his last name, for effect or other reasons, it is the normal spelling, that is all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 5):

A shade is a demon.  Fifty Shades means fifty demons.  Throughout the trilogy there are frequent references to Christian Grey's demons; those are his shades. (NB Pay close attention to the meaning of the names throughout the trilogy.)  The fifty demons comes from a Buddhist book titled 50 demons.